# Java Scanner null out put

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using `Scanner` to read a file with different extension that a text file normally has but with same content as text file. 
If I do use `Scanner` on **text.txt** extension then I do get out put but when I perform same task on the different extension but with same content that I don't get any output at all.

After performing different test, it seen that the problem are those characters: `“ ”`

Any clue why same file with different extension got different behaviors?

file:

```
“1 line”
2nd line
3 rd line
```

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    String path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\t1.RANDOM";

    File file = new File(path);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            sb.append(sc.nextLine()+"\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: Try printing `file.exists()` to see if the file exists. You may took the wrong path. Additionally use @"PATH HERE WITHOUT DOUBLE \"

Comment: @OrelEraki That's why the `FileNotFoudException` is there. The constructor Scanner(File) throws it when the file does not exist + the double \\ is necessary, a back slash has to be escaped in a string literal.

Comment: @OrelEraki, it was my first thought, but normaly if file doesnt exsist exception will take care of it. Those files does exist in such location. There is different problem which I cant find =S

Comment: @user1768615 This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901316/curly-quotes-causing-java-scanner-hasnextline-to-be-false-why

Comment: What other task are you performing? The above code has no errors. It might be something wrong with the other tasks you are doing.

Comment: @HernánErasmo, I'm performing random test and as far only with quotes I do have problem, useful link thanks.

Comment: just a sanity check - do you press **ctrl + s** after copying content... :P .. kidding

The above code look good..

Comment: Problem is encoding, hrhr, need to find right encoding for scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might think `Scanner` is doing different stream reading if it doesn't identify a known extension.
Maybe try using the following constructor:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Found already answer in google hehe, but since u wrote it here u deserv have +1 and best answer. thanks!