# How to prevent storing of text coming between special characters /* and */ in arraylist in java

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am reading a pl/sql code from a text file and storing all words of it into array list from below code :

```
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(file1);
ArrayList<String> Code1 = new ArrayList<String>();
in1.useDelimiter("(\\p{javaWhitespace}|\\.|,)+");
while (in1.hasNext())
    {
        Code1.add(in1.next().toLowerCase());
    }
```

Everything is working fine but i am facing issue whenever there is a comments section in code written in between special character /* and */.Like below:

```
/* 
|| This is a comments section in pl/sql code...||
|| Which i don't want to store..               ||
*/
```

How can i modify my code so that it will not store whatever comes in between /* and */

Comment: It sounds like this doesn't have anything to do with ArrayList... that's just going to store whatever you add. I'm not sure that using Scanner is going to give you enough power, here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an alternative delimiter - multiline comments.

```
in1.useDelimiter("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|[\\p{javaWhitespace}.,]+");
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/oFAFHI):

```
String s = "Some text. More, more text. /* \n|| This is a comments section in pl/sql code...||\n|| Which i don't want to store..               ||\n*/ SOME HERE";
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(s);
ArrayList<String> Code1 = new ArrayList<String>();
in1.useDelimiter("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|[\\p{javaWhitespace}.,]+");
while (in1.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(in1.next().toLowerCase());
}
```

Results:

```
some
text
more
more
text
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks , Using this as delimiter is ignoring the comments section but i land up into one more issue regarding this. Below is the comments section in the file /*  application is “in process” */

Comment: But not if  “in process”  is there , basically if i remove double quotes from word in comment its working fine but not if i keep as it is.

Comment: when i am keeping word  “in process”  as it is in comments the whole file is not getting read. Everything is working fine as expected if i remove the double quotes from my comments

Comment: below is my actual comment in the file /* This code will check application  “in process” from the file*/

Comment: Aha, see [**Curly quotes causing Java Scanner hasNextLine() to be false — why?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901316/curly-quotes-causing-java-scanner-hasnextline-to-be-false-why). It is not the regex to blame, just use appropriate encoding.

Comment: I want not to store anything which comes in between comments   /* This code will check application “in process” from the file */ . currently your solution is working perfect if i remove double quotes from word in process in comments

Comment: Yeah agree its not regex to blame , its related with encoding now. checking the link you posted.

Comment: I got it now Thanks Wiktor. I got the solution for both issues :)

Comment: Hey Wiktor, Could you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/37631426/6201003?sgp=2 This is regarding the same type of question  as this one

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by substringing the string you want to store in the arrayList. Just search for those special characters inside your strings and if they exist you only have to remove them. From /* to */

this is the method you can use to cut out the unwanted piece
`public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

to check if the String got those special characters, you can use the matches methode. Just use a regular expression

you can finde everything you need here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html