# How to prevent storing of text coming after special characters -- in arraylist in java

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am reading a pl/sql code from a text file and storing all words of it into array list from below code :

```
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(file1);
ArrayList<String> Code1 = new ArrayList<String>();
in1.useDelimiter("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|[\\p{javaWhitespace}\\.|,]+");
while (in1.hasNext())
  {
    Code1.add(in1.next().toLowerCase());
  }
```

Everything is working fine but i am facing issue whenever there is a comments section in code written in after special character -- Like below:

```
select * from 
Dummy_Table --This is a, dummy.table
where id = 1 -- Filter.on, id
```

For above code i don't want to store the comments (--This is a, dummy.table) and (-- Filter.on, id) in my list.How can i do this ?

```
in1.useDelimiter("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|[\\p{javaWhitespace}\\.|,]+");
```

I am using above delimiter to skip reading comment section enclosed between /*  and */, which is multiple line comments as written below but including this i also want to skip reading/storing the single statement comments i.e. after -- till the end of line.

```
/* 
|| This is a comments section in pl/sql code...||
|| Which i don't want to store..               ||
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add part after `--` till end of line in your regex like this:

```
in1.useDelimiter("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|--[^\\n]*|[\\p{javaWhitespace}\\.|,]+");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gN3eJ9/1)

Comment: Good idea.Thanks :) This might work, let me check it once

Comment: This is working but i am getting line break in output where there is comments which i dont want

Comment: Try `in1.useDelimiter("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/|--[^\\n]*[\\r\\n]+|[\\p{javaWhitespace}‌​\\.|,]+");`

Answer (score 0):

For removing inline comments, have you considered using the simple combination of `indexOf()` and `substring()`?  Also, should you be using `in1.nextLine()` instead of `in1.next()`?  For example:

```
while (in1.hasNext())
{
    String line = in1.nextLine();
    int indexOfComment = line.indexOf("--");
    if (indexOfComment > -1) {
        line = line.substring(0, indexOfComment);
    }
    Code1.add(line.toLowerCase());
}
```